# How to define a nice name?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a poset and $B,D$ be sets.

Let $p \in \mathbb{P}$ and  $\sigma$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-name such that $p \Vdash \sigma \in B$. Then there exist a nice name $\tau$ for an object in $B$ such that $p \Vdash \sigma = \tau.$

Also if  $\mu$  be a $\mathbb{P}$-name such that $p \Vdash \mu:D\to B$ Then there exist a nice name $\pi$ for a function from $D$ into $B$ such that $p \Vdash \mu = \pi.$

I am studying the book Kunen and I'm a little confused when defining a $\mathbb{P}$-name.

A suggestion of how to define a nice name. Thanks

Comment: For "some" reason this question has been asked like four times in the past week. It got an answer, but then the question just reappears again and again and again. Maybe we can stop doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Although Neil already wrote what the idea behind nice names is, I decided to add some details, since almost each forcing textbook covers this topic in a different way.

Before giving all the formal details - repetition of what Neil wrote, in slightly different words, with applications to names for subsets of $\omega$:
a name $\sigma$ for a subset of $\omega$ in general consists of pairs of the form $(\check{n}, p)$. The requirement for $\sigma$ to be a nice name is that for every such $\check{n}$ the set of $p \in \mathbb{P}$ paired with this $\check{n}$ in $\sigma$ forms an antichain.

To fulfill this requirement we will try to define a nice name $\sigma$ for a given name $\pi$ for a subset of $\omega$ by choosing for each name $\check{n}$ (i.e. each name for element of $\omega$) a (maximal) antichain of conditions *forcing $n$ into* $\pi_G$. That is, we try to define $\sigma$ so that the abovementioned $p$'s form a maximal antichain $A_n$ and force that $n \in \pi_G$. Then we will consider the set of conditions stronger then some element of $A_n$ and demosntrate it is dense, therefore an element of this set will be in the generic filter $G$, and as Neil wrote - generic filter has to intersect maximal antichains, so it will in particular contain a condition that is a righ-coordinate of some element of our nice name $\sigma$ which in effect will show that every subset of $\omega$ has a nice name. This will allow us to control the number of possible names of subsets of $\omega$, as long as we are able to control the sizes of the antichains in $\mathbb{P}$.

Now, to the details:

Let $\sigma, \tau \in M^\mathbb{P}$. The name $\sigma$ is a **nice name for a subset of** $\tau$ if $dom(\sigma) \subseteq dom(\tau)$ and:
$$\forall \eta \in dom(\sigma) \: \forall p, q \in \mathbb{P} \: ((\eta, p) \in \sigma \: \wedge \: (\eta, q) \in \sigma \: \wedge \: p \neq q) \Rightarrow p \bot q,$$
which is the same thing as to say that for every $\eta \in dom(\sigma)$ the set of condition *paired* with $\eta$ in $\sigma$, i.e. the set $$\{p \in \mathbb{P}: (\eta, p) \in \sigma\}$$
is an antichain.

Having a name $\tau$, and some name $\pi$ for its subset (i.e. such that $M[G] \models \pi_G \subseteq \tau_G$) we can always define a nice name $\sigma$ for the subset $\pi$ of $\tau$ (that's a first nice thing about the nice names):

**Lemma:** For any $\tau, \pi \in M^\mathbb{P}$ there exists a nice name $\sigma \in M^\mathbb{P}$ for a subset of $\tau$ such that:
$$1_\mathbb{P} \Vdash \pi \subseteq \tau \Rightarrow \sigma = \pi.$$

The proof of the lemma gives an exact answer to your original question on how to define nice $\sigma$:

**Proof:** Let $M[G] \models \pi_G \subseteq \tau_G$. By the forcing theorem there is a condition $q \in G$ such that $$q \Vdash \pi \subseteq \tau.$$
Now we get into the defition of a nice name: for every $\eta \in dom(\tau)$ we define:
$$B_\eta := \{p \leq q: p \Vdash \eta \in \pi\}. (\ast)$$
By the Kuratowski-Zorn Lemma there is a maximal antichain $A_\eta \subseteq B_\eta$.

Define the name $\sigma$ as:
$$\sigma = \{(\eta, p): \eta \in dom(\tau) \: \wedge \: p \in A_\eta\}.(\ast \ast)$$

Observe that $\sigma$ is a nice name for **a** subset of $\tau$ by definition (since $A_\eta$ was chosen to be an antichain), so the *only* thing we need to demonstrate is that $M[G] \models \sigma_G = \pi_G$.

The easier part is to show that $M[G] \models \sigma_G \subseteq \pi_G$. Indeed: suppose $M[G] \models \eta_G \in \sigma_G$. By definition it means that there is a condition $p \in G$ s.t. $M \models (\eta, p) \in \sigma$., i.e. $\eta \in dom(\tau)$ and $p \in A_\eta$, which by the definition of $A_\eta$ in particular means that $p \Vdash \eta \in \pi$ (since $A_\eta \subseteq B_\eta$). But then it just means that in $M[G]$ we have $\eta_G \in \pi_G$ - exactly what we wanted.

Now, the reverse inclusion is more interesting, and it is here that we will use the fact that $A_\eta$ is an antichain: we claim that $\pi_G \subseteq \sigma_G$. So assume $\eta_G \in \pi_G$. Now, instead of invoking the definition of $G$-values, we again refer to the forcing theorem: it means there is a condition $p_0 \in G$ such that $$p_0 \Vdash \eta \in \pi$$
(by the fact that $G$ is a filter $G$ (in particular - downwards directed), we can assume $p_0 \leq q$).

Now define the following set:

$$D = \{ p \in \mathbb{P}: p \: || \: p_0 \Rightarrow \exists r \in A_\eta \: p \leq r\}.$$

We first claim that $D$ is dense - then we will use the genericity of $G$ to conclude the proof with showing $\eta_G \in \sigma_G$.

To show that $D$ is dense, let $p_1 \in \mathbb{P}$ be any forcing condition. Suppose $p_1 \: || \: p_0$ (otherwise $p_1$ is already in $D$ itself) - this just means there is $p_2 \leq p_0, p_1$. Since $p_0 \Vdash \eta \in \pi$, we also know that $$p_2 \Vdash \eta \in \pi,$$ in other words that $$p_2 \in B_\eta.$$
Here comes the crucial step: since $A_\eta$ is a maximal antichain in $B_\eta$, there must be some $r \in A_\eta$ s.t. $p_2 \: || \: r$ (otherwise, $A_\eta \cup \{p_2\}$ would be an antichain striclty extending $A_\eta$), so there is a condition $p_3 \leq p_2, r$ that satisfies the defining condition of $D$, and obviously, by construction: $p_3 \leq p_1$, which proves the density claim.

So now, by genericity (and which is exactly what the last sentence of Neil's answer refers to), there has to be a condition $p \in G \cap D$, i.e. $p \in G$ such that $$p \bot p_0 \: \vee \: \exists r \in A_\eta \: p \leq r,$$
but since $p_0 \in G$, $p$ and $p_0$ have to be compatible, so $$\exists r \in A_\eta \: p \leq r.$$ But $G$ is a filter, so by the fact that $p \in G$, and $p \leq r$ we have $r \in G$ and $r \in A_\eta$, i.e. $(\eta, r) \in \sigma$ (definition of $A_\eta$!), that is:
$$\exists r \in G \: (\eta, r) \in \sigma,$$
which by the definition of $G$-values means that in $M[G]$ we have $\eta_G \in \sigma_G$, exactly as promised. $\square$

Comments about the proof:

$(\ast)$ You actually do not need to restrict to $p \leq q$ but it's neat this way.  - what is essential is that $B_\eta$ consists of these conditions that force $\eta$ to be an element of a given subset $\pi$ of $\tau$.

$(\ast \ast)$ As you can see, the definition of the nice name $\sigma$ is relative not only to $\tau$, but also to $\pi$, because $A_\eta$ is chosen as a subset of $B_\eta$ that depends on $\pi$. An important thing here is that you can think of the nice name $\sigma$ as of a function $f_\sigma: \eta \mapsto A_\eta$, i.e. roughly speaking : mapping each candidate $\eta$ for a member of $\tau$ to a maximal antichain of conditions forcing that $\eta$ is an element of the subset $\pi$ of $\tau$ (I wrote roughly speaking, because these are all obviously just names of sets, canidates etc. but I assume it's clear).

The above rather answers your question, but now -  why do we want to have nice names after all?

Well, the reason is as follows - and this is the essence of nice names: if we know a bound on possible sizes of antichains in $\mathbb{P}$, then we can also control how many antichains there are in $\mathbb{P}$, and  further - thanks to having nice names for subsets of $\tau$, i.e. for elements of $\mathcal{P}(\tau)$ - we are able to control the size of $\mathcal{P}(\tau_G)$. To be precise we have the following:

**Fact:** If $\mathbb{P}$ has c.c.c., and $\tau \in M^\mathbb{P}$, then:
$$M[G] \models |\mathcal{P}(\tau_G)| \leq (|\mathbb{P}|^{\aleph_0 \cdot |dom(\tau)|})^M.$$

Now, as an example: when you take $\mathbb{P}$ to be Cohen forcing $Fn(\kappa \times \omega, 2)$, assume $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$ (or actually, that $cf(\kappa) > \aleph_0$), and $\tau_G$ to be $\omega$ (and then $\eta$'s are just names for natural numbers), what do you get?

Comment: In particular we can use nice names to show that if $(\Bbb P$ is c.c.c. and $|\Bbb P|\le 2^{\omega})^M$ then forcing with $\Bbb P$ over $M$ preserves the $\beth$ (beth) function, which is handy sometimes, e.g. to show the consistency of ($\neg CH$ and some free ultra-filter on $\omega$ is $\omega_1$-generated.)

Answer (score 4):

A nice name can be defined as followed:

**Definition IV.3.8** (In the 2013 edition of the Kunen) For $\tau \in V^{\mathbb{P}}$, a *nice name for a subset of $\tau$* is a name of the form $\cup \{ \{\sigma \} \times A_{\sigma} | \sigma \in dom(\tau)\}$, where each $A_\sigma$ is an antichain in $\mathbb{P}$.

So a nice name for a subset of $\tau$ is one where you look at $\mathbb{P}$-names in the domain of $\tau$ (i.e. candidates for members of subsets of $\tau$), index antichains in $\mathbb{P}$ using these names, and then look at the set of ordered pairs you can make whose first coordinates are each $\sigma$, and second coordinates are the members of the antichain indeced by $\sigma$.

Essentially, you want to have names that interact nicely with the antichains in $\mathbb{P}$. The lemmas you mention show that you can find nice names that will do the job of normal $\mathbb{P}$-names, but give you a little more traction on what's going on with the antichains in $\mathbb{P}$ during a forcing construction. Remember any $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $\mathfrak{M}$ has to intersect a maximal antichain of $\mathbb{P}$. So, by using a nice name $\theta$ for a subset of $\tau$ (and where the antichain $A_{\sigma}$ is maximal, you're guaranteeing that for each $\sigma \in dom(\theta)$, $\sigma_G$ makes it into $\theta_G \subseteq \tau_G$, as the generic can't avoid including it.

Comment: hello, Neil how to define $\tau$ and $\pi$. Thanks.